# Como exibir um texto com múltiplas linhas com format?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

Ando tentando por várias linhas seguidas com uma só *string* junto com o método `.format`, mas não consigo.

```
a=input("digite algo; ")
print("""contem maiusculos:{}  contem: {}n\contem números: {}  contem
alfanumericos: {}""".format(a.isupper(),a.isnumeric(),a.isalnum()))
```

No caso, ele está dando erro por estar fora do escopo, mas já tentei de outras formas, mas sempre acaba que não consigo usar o método `.format` ou apenas parcialmente.

Neste caso eu ainda precisarei de mais linha, pois usarei mais métodos do que os já listados no exemplo.

Comment: Oi matheus! Em relação à tua resposta/nova duvida. Se estiver relacionada com a resposta do @AndersonCarlosWoss comenta lá na resposta dele. Senão podes criar uma nova pergunta.

Comment: se eu por exemplo mencionar o autor da resposta e depois mencionar uma duvida eu estaria ferindo a regra quanto a criação de tópicos?

Comment: Se tens uma dúvida qualquer um pode responder. Se quiseres podes colocar um comentário aqui na resposta do Anderson para indicar o link da outra pergunta.

Comment: ok muito obrigado. pela paciência.

Answer (score 5):

Pelo o que entendi, você quer que se a saída seja exibida em múltiplas linhas. Da forma que está, resulta no erro:

> *IndexError: tuple index out of range*

Pelo simples fato que sua *string* espera 4 valores para ser formatada corretamente e você passa apenas 3. Portanto, tal erro seria suprido passando o quarto parâmetro ao `format`, seja ele qual for.

O problema da quebra de linha se dá, aparentemente, porque você tentou fazer a quebra de linha com `n\`, enquanto o caractere de quebra de linha é `\n`. Mas utilizando a *string* entre três aspas, como está fazendo, não haverá a necessidade de utilizar tal caractere. A própria quebra de linha na *string* fará com que quebre a linha na saída.

Veja um exemplo:

```
a = input("Digite algo: ")

saida = """
Você digitou: {}
O texto possui {} caracteres
O texto é um valor numérico? {}
"""

print(saida.format(a, len(a), a.isnumeric()))
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/BjzdY4) | [Repl.it](https://repl.it/NbKi/0)</sup>

Exemplos de saída:

```
>>> Digite algo: Anderson Carlos Woss

Você digitou: Anderson Carlos Woss
O texto possui 20 caracteres
O texto é um valor numérico? False

>>> Digite algo: 2017

Você digitou: 2017
O texto possui 4 caracteres
O texto é um valor numérico? True
```

Comment: muito obrigado cara pela ajuda, me ajudou muito.^^

Answer (score 1):

Hoje com a versão python3 você pode usar as fstrings da seguinte forma:

```py
a = input("Digite algo: ")

print(f"""
Você digitou: {a}
O texto possui {len(a)} caracteres
O texto é um valor numérico? {a.isnumeric()}""")
```

Saída:

```
>>> Digite algo: Seu nome

Você digitou: Seu nome
O texto possui 8 caracteres
O texto é um valor numérico? False

>>> Digite algo: 2019

Você digitou: 2019
O texto possui 4 caracteres
O texto é um valor numérico? True
```